# Read compass heading just once

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

So i'm working on an android application for android, and I'm using the compass plugin.
I followed the instructions from the phonegap website, and it all works fine, except one thing.

The first example (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_compass_compass.md.html#Compass) should give the heading (the degree) in an alert once, but the value is always 0! But why?

So I have worked on the code, so it would look like the second example (without buttons). This code checks en displays the degree every second. Now the value isn't 0, but between 1 and 360. 
this is the value i want, but i don't want it every second, i want it just once. Is there a way to check it just once?

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.compass.getCurrentHeading(onSuccess, onError);
}

// onSuccess: Get the current heading
function onSuccess(heading) {
    alert('Heading: ' + heading.magneticHeading);
}

// onError: Failed to get the heading
function onError(compassError) {
    alert('Compass Error: ' + compassError.code);
}
```

So this is the standard javascript, and this code should give the heading juist once, but it always gives 0.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// The watch id references the current `watchHeading`
var watchID = null;

// Wait for Cordova to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
    startWatch();
}

// Start watching the compass
function startWatch() {
    var options = { frequency: 100 };
    watchID = navigator.compass.watchHeading(onSuccess, onError, options);
}

// Stop watching the compass
function stopWatch() {
    if (watchID) {
        navigator.compass.clearWatch(watchID);
        watchID = null;
    }
}

// onSuccess: Get the current heading
function onSuccess(heading) {
    var element = document.getElementById('heading');
    element.innerHTML = heading.magneticHeading;

    if (heading.magneticHeading > 180) {
        document.getElementById('background').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('background').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }
}

// onError: Failed to get the heading
function onError(compassError) {
    alert('Compass error: ' + compassError.code);
}
});
```

This code works, but it checks if not once, but multple times a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the full code you're using, I'd say the first example may be giving zero because the device is not ready (you'll notice that in the second example, the call to watchHeading is not made until after the deviceready event fires).

As for the second issue, this is because watchHeading continuously requests feedback (controlled by the frequency option).  After you get the ID for the watch, you need to call clearWatch and pass it that ID to stop.

If you're just trying to get a single heading, just call getHeading rather than watchHeading.  But do so only after the device is ready.

**---Edit---**

This bugged me enough to build your project and test it out on my Droid 4 (running 4.1.2).  Returning 0 -is- normal behavior; that's just the compass warming up (similar to GPS where you want to throw out the first number of coordinates you receive as they are typically stale).  Usually just one call is enough to warm it up, and after that you will receive good data.

Since you don't want a constant feedback, I would warm up the compass on app start (just call getCurrentHeading once), then call getCurrentHeading again whenever you need.

Alternatively, go ahead and receive feedback every few seconds as there's no harm in just storing the latest compass heading and it keeps the compass primed.  Then when you want your app to make use of the data, you can either just call getCurrentHeading or use the stored compass data.

Comment: I have edited my post. I copied the code from phonegap. As you can see, it already uses getCurrentHeading, and it only uses it when the device is ready.

Comment: What device & OS version are you testing this on?

Comment: HTC desire, and Android, and yes, the phone has a compass

Comment: And standard check, but you've enabled the appropriate permissions?

Comment: Yes, i have opdated m post, the last code works perfect on my phone. but nu it checks the "heading" 10 times a second. when i change it to once every 10 seconds, the first 10 seconds, the value is 0.

Comment: Updated my answer; hopefully that helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call stopWatch() from inside onSuccess() since youv'e told watchHeading() to repeat every 100 ms.